# Having trouble using string

Tags: c

Q) Help out our canteen and develop a program for cash
counter where user selects items out of 5 options with price .
The program keeps on asking until user hit 'q'. After check
out calculate total amount and show user the items purchased.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char menu[5][15]={"Pizza","Burger","Ice Cream","Pasta","Cold Drink"};
    int price[5]={1000,500,300,100,50};
    int i,amount=0,total=0,item=0;
    printf("\t\t=========ALI FAST FOOD========");
    printf("\n\t\tPlease select any option from below\n");
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\nAvailable items are %s press %d",menu[i],item+1);
        printf("\tPrice is %d",price[i]);
        printf("\n");
        item++;
    }
    int choice;
    int start;
    printf("Enter number to start buying food");
    do {

    scanf("\n%d ",&choice);
    if (choice==1)
        {
            static int count=0;
            amount = amount+price[0];
            printf("\nYou bought %d %s",count+1,menu[0]);
            count++;
        }
        else if (choice==2)
        {
            static int count=0;
            amount = amount+price[1];
            printf("\nYou bought %d %s",count+1,menu[1]);
            count++;
        }
        else if (choice==3)
        {
            static int count=0;
            amount = amount+price[2];
            printf("\nYou bought %d %s",count+1,menu[2]);
            count++;
        }
        else if (choice==4)
        {
            static int count=0;
            amount = amount+price[3];
            printf("\nYou bought %d %s",count+1,menu[3]);
            count++;
    }
    else if (choice==5)
        {
            int count=0;
            amount = amount+price[4];
            printf("\nYou bought %d %s",count+1,menu[4]);
            count++;
    }

    else if (choice==0 || choice>=7)
    {
        printf("\nEnter correct option please\n");

    }
}

     while (choice!=6);


    total = total + amount;
    printf("\nTotal amount to be pay is %d",total);
    printf("\nThank you for visiting our canteen have a nice day !");
}
```

In this i need to end the program when user enters "q" instead of "6" . i am unable to do so, please help me fix this issue.

Comment: read in a _character_ instead of a number (preferably using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`. Then check for a 'q' and otherwise convert it to an integer.

Comment: we are not taught fgets yet, can't i use scanf ? with some other tricks? what do you mean by convert it to an integer?

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &choice);` and then `if (choice == '1')`. You'll handle caracters instead of integers

Comment: i used %c but it's not working correctly for some reason.

Comment: @Incognito: Make sure you have a blank space in front of the `%c` in the format string - `" %c"`.  Unlike most conversion specifiers, `%c` won't skip any leading whitespace, so you need the leading space in the format string to consume any leading whitespace and `%c` will pick up the first *non*-whitespace character.

Comment: @JohnBode thanks, but in my compiler, it's other way around i guess, my program is running fine if i don't give space after and before %c.

Comment: There's some code reuse here that doesn't have to be there. `count` is problematic because it cannot be accessed outside the scope it was declared in; maybe `struct { const char *const item; const int price; int count; } menu[] = { { "Pizza", 1000, 0 }, ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

- As suggested by "Cid" try handling the input as characters instead of
  integers.
- Also, as suggested by "JohnBode" use a blank space before "%c" and
  *not before and after* "%c"(i suspect that you tried using a blank
  space after the "%c" as well). Let me know if I am mistaken.

Putting it together, you code should look like this....

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char menu[5][15]={"Pizza","Burger","Ice Cream","Pasta","Cold Drink"};
   int price[5]={1000,500,300,100,50};
   int i,amount=0,total=0,item=0;
   printf("\t\t=========ALI FAST FOOD========");
   printf("\n\t\tPlease select any option from below\n");
   for (i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      printf("\nAvailable items are %s press %d",menu[i],item+1);
      printf("\tPrice is %d",price[i]);
      printf("\n");
      item++;
   }
   char choice;
   int start;
   printf("Enter number to start buying food\n");
   do {
     scanf(" %c",&choice);
     if (choice=='1')
     {
        static int count=0;
        amount = amount+price[0];
        printf("\nYou bought %d %s\n",count+1,menu[0]);
        count++;
     }
    else if (choice=='2')
    {
        static int count=0;
        amount = amount+price[1];
        printf("\nYou bought %d %s\n",count+1,menu[1]);
        count++;
    }
    else if (choice=='3')
    {
        static int count=0;
        amount = amount+price[2];
        printf("\nYou bought %d %s\n",count+1,menu[2]);
        count++;
    }
    else if (choice=='4')
    {
        static int count=0;
        amount = amount+price[3];
        printf("\nYou bought %d %s\n",count+1,menu[3]);
        count++;
    }
   else if (choice=='5')
   {
        int count=0;
        amount = amount+price[4];
        printf("\nYou bought %d %s\n",count+1,menu[4]);
        count++;
   }
   //checking for lower and upper case "q"
   else if (choice=='0' || choice >= '6' && (choice != 'q' && choice != 'Q'))
   {
    printf("\nEnter correct option please\n");

   }
} while (choice!='q' && choice!='Q');//checking for lower and upper case "q"


  total = total + amount;
  printf("\nTotal amount to be pay is %d\n",total);
  printf("\nThank you for visiting our canteen have a nice day !\n");
}
```